# Can Sitecore JavaScript Services (JSS) be used with a Sitecore Experience Manager (XM) configuration?

Tags: jss

Does Sitecore JavaScript Services (JSS) require Sitecore Experience Platform (XP) or can it be used with a Sitecore Experience Manager (XM) configuration?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes there is a XM version of JSS (without XConnect)
See the downloads:
https://dev.sitecore.net/Downloads/Sitecore_JavaScript_Services/110/Sitecore_JavaScript_Services_1100.aspx

Comment: Thanks - I couldn't find this detail on the JSS documentation website.